# Automating the installation process

Tags: java, c#, windows, selenium, cmd

I need to install one `xyz.exe` file and need to work on some URL after installation. I am working in Java environment and automating the web app by using `WebDriver`.

My further step is to automate that installation of `xyz.exe` as first step before going to browser automation. I tried by best and found below command to execute from `cmd`:

```
  start "" /w xyz.exe
```

But I am stuck in next step as need to handle

> 1. click on ok
> 2. select dropdown value and click on next
> 3. click on agree
> 4. enter username and password

I know `AutoIT` tool but looking for some other which works in others OS so that my Dev team also use the same.

Please help me with some suggestions, tools, links to move forward..

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 1):

Depending on who supplied that file they might provide the option to submit parameters when running the program (i.e. "xyz.exe EULAACCEPT=1 USER=xyz PASSWD=abc ...") but I can just guess as there is no standard and everyone has its own parameters (or none at all). Some also work with so called "answer files". You might find that in documentation, google or ask the supplier for assistance.

Another option would be to track registry and file changes while you run the file and enter all the details... after finishing the installation process you will get a summary what files where installed and what was changed in registry. Out of that you could create a new installer or MSI for redistribution. There is several tools that will do the job.

Comment: Yes, actually i am also looking for same to get parameters. But known that code under developers so before requesting them, i am looking for any other way to get those parameters from installer it self.

Answer (score 0):

Hi murali seleniumtrainer please go for Sikuli and learn it form here http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripting.html the best part of sikuli is

```
1. it works great and efficiently
2. also have java api so no need to learn new language
3. you can easily integrate your webdriver code with siklu hence giving you power 
for bot desktop as well as browser in the same language
```

Comment: thanks for info, actually i am not looking by using tools like sikuli, autoit..looking to do from command prompt with out tools so that my dev team also use this where ever they required without bothering tool is installed or not